# Replacing only first HTML tag on a page in RegEx

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

I would like to search for only the first occurrence of an HTML tag (and it's contents) and replace it for another. I want the search and replace to stop after it's found the first occurrence on a page.

For example, at the top of each page in a directory is:

```
 <h3>This is my title</h3>
```

I want to search and replace the h3 tag with an h1 tag and leaving the contents of tag the same. So that the outputted result would be:

```
 <h1>This is my title</h1>
```

The "this is my title" portion is different on each page. I will be using a Microsoft Server program on the server (called fnr.exe) that does search and replace and can handle regex.

I only want this to occur on first instance of each document that I am running this find and replace with.

I have tried 
find: /h3>/g
replace: /h1>

That did not work. I'm not sure what else to do.

This is what my MS program looks like:

[image]

I've also tried to use another program which seems popular for windows called Notepad++. This is a screenshot of that attempt. It replaced all occurances. (For testing on this one, I tried to find only the first h2 tag and replace it with h1. It replaced all the h2 tags.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything. Should we assume that you want to use JavaScript?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying "I want to replace the first <h1> tag on a page with an <h3> tag with the same content".  Is that correct?

Comment: apologies, I originally said I was using MS, which I thought would be understood as Microsoft. I have edited the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any MS programs so you're going to have to test this out on your own but I think this should do what you are after.

Search for

```
^([\s\S]*?)<h3>(.*?)</h3>
```

replace with

```
$1<h1>$2</h1>
```

Demo and explanation of regex, https://regex101.com/r/tB6rV2/2

Comment: that replace all my instances of h3 on the page. I've updated question to include screenshot of how my program looks in MS.

Comment: What program is that?

Comment: It's called fnr.exe (Find and Replace)

Comment: While it seems that engine doesn't support the `^` as the start of a new string (presumptions based off 20 seconds of goolging). Could you use some other approach/engine?

Comment: Thanks!  I would've done the 20 second google search myself except that I'm so ignorant on this that I didn't know what to search for. I have tried using another program which seems to be popular for Windows called Notepad++. I placed screenshot in edit above. I used your provided code (except I used h2 instead of h3) and it replaced all instances of h2's, not just the first one.

Comment: Hmm works in Dreamweaver for me, that is on the first pass it replaces all? I'm mac based so cant test notepad++ either.

Comment: I ended up using Dreamweaver and it worked. Thanks! I wanted to do it straight on the server, but went ahead and downloaded the site, did the replace in Dreamweaver, then uploaded site. Alls good.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just search for `/h3>/g` and replace with `h1>`

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work. Nothing was "found" when searching for /h3>/g

Comment: This is going to replace all `h3`s to `h1`s, not just the first one. Also not sure if MS expects delimiters..